# Google Translate API - Access Denied Error 403

Tags: api, translation

I am using Google API for one of my project. I completed all the formalities with google. I pay the bill for using it. But I cannot move out with one issue. If I send data for translation back to back, google reverts back with Access denied Error 403. So I had to put some delay in my code. But as a matter of fact total time is increasing. So what is the possible way to recover this issue.
I am using C# dot net to call the google API.

```
> https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&q={0}&source=en &target=sv
```

Answer (score 2):

From Google translate API FAQ page:

> You may be exceeding your quota: either the daily billable total, or the limit on request characters per second.
>   To view or change usage limits for your project, or to request an increase to your quota, do the following:

For more information [Google translate API FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/translate/faq)